# How do I get thomasp85/gganimate to work properly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have the following code from the following site : https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/288-animated-barplot-transition/

```
# libraries:
library(tidyverse)
library(tweenr)
library(gganimate)

# Make 2 basic barplots
a=data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(3,2,4), frame=rep('a',3))
b=data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(5,3,7), frame=rep('b',3))
data=rbind(a,b)

# Basic barplot:
ggplot(a, aes(x=group, y=values, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')

# Interpolate data with tweenr
ts <- list(a, b, a)
tf <- tween_states(ts, tweenlength = 0.02, statelength = 0.001, ease = c('cubic-in-out'), nframes = 30)
tf

# Make a barplot with frame
p=ggplot(tf, aes(x=group, y=values, fill=group, frame= .frame)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = "identity")
gganimate(p, interval = .1, title_frame = F, filename="#288_barplot_animation.gif", ani.width=480, ani.height=480)
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get it to work since gganimate doesn't work on R 3.5.1 and I have installed `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate")` so the code is different.

Comment: That's code for the old version of gganimate. You may be able to install it with `install_github` if you specify the commit, but the new version is much more powerful. Now it does the tweening for you, so instead of `tween_states` before you plot, you just add `transition_states` to the ggplot itself.

Comment: How would I go about converting the old code to the new code?

Answer (score 3):

That code is for the original version of gganimate by @drob, not the current reincarnation by @thomasp85. The new style handles the tweening by adding steps to the ggplot call, so `tween_states` is replaced by `transition_states`. To specify the ease, add `ease_aes`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

df <- rbind(
    data.frame(group = c("A","B","C"), values = c(3,2,4), frame = rep('a',3)),
    data.frame(group = c("A","B","C"), values = c(5,3,7), frame = rep('b',3))
)

ggplot(df, aes(group, values, fill = group)) + 
    geom_col(position = "identity") + 
    transition_states(frame, .02, .001) + 
    ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
```

[image]

If you want to adjust `fps` or plot size, assign the plot to an object and call `animate` on it with the desired settings. To save, use `anim_save`.